# Can't add a migration anymore

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF Core. Works well, but from this morinng I have this error message when I try to create a migration:

**Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandParsingException: Unrecognized option '--startup-project'    at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.HandleUnexpectedArg(CommandLineApplication command, String[] args, Int32 index, String argTypeName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Unrecognized option '--startup-project'**

Does anybody knows this issue? I could not find any informations.
I checked, the default project is the correct one, migrations are enabled and I already successfully added migrations.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the exact command that you are trying to use? Since I don't have enoguh info this is just a suggestion: Try setting the startup project as the one that contains the connections strings. When using PM, be sure to select the correct project(this is not necessarily the startup project but it might as well be.) that contains the EF assemblies.

Comment: I run: add-migration CoordonneesFiches

Comment: do you using EF Core with .NET Core or with .NET full version (4.6)

Comment: using EF core with .net full version

Comment: did you get this fixed? exact same problem here.